# Trying to get property 'roles' of non-object, i have this problem

Tags: php, html, laravel-8

**I am working with: Laravel 8, Spatie, Laravel Collective**

im workin on sisteme to login with roles and when i try to enter of view user.edit, i have this problem.

I noticed that if I put the id of the user that I want to edit manually in the url it works perfectly but when I do it from the edit button it throws me the error, I don't know if it has something to do with it but I noticed that.

**UsuarioController:**

```
    public function edit($id)
    {
        $user = User::find($id);
        $roles = Role::pluck('name','name')->all();
        $userRole = $user->roles->pluck('name','name')->all();
    
        return view('usuarios.editar',compact('user','roles','userRole'));
    }

    
    public function update(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $this->validate($request, [
            'name' => 'required',
            'email' => 'required|email|unique:users,email,'.$id,
            'password' => 'same:confirm-password',
            'roles' => 'required'
        ]);
    
        $input = $request->all();
        if(!empty($input['password'])){ 
            $input['password'] = Hash::make($input['password']);
        }else{
            $input = Arr::except($input,array('password'));    
        }
    
        $user = User::find($id);
        $user->update($input);
        DB::table('model_has_roles')->where('model_id',$id)->delete();
    
        $user->assignRole($request->input('roles'));
    
        return redirect()->route('usuarios.index');
    }
```

**User Edit View:**

```
{!! Form::model($user, ['method' => 'PATCH','route' => ['usuarios.update', $user->id]]) !!}
                        <div class="row">
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="name">Nombre</label>
                                    {!! Form::text('name', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="email">E-mail</label>
                                    {!! Form::text('email', null, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password">Password</label>
                                    {!! Form::password('password', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="password_confirmation">Confirmar Password</label>
                                    {!! Form::password('password_confirmation', array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <div class="form-group">
                                    <label for="">Roles</label>
                                    {!! Form::select('roles[]', $roles,$userRole, array('class' => 'form-control')) !!}
                                </div>
                            </div>
                            <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-12">
                                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Guardar</button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                        {!! Form::close() !!}
```